# Amazon Redshift: Joining two columns where column content is slightly different

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I tried everything I could possibly find in this forum. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
Exam Name
-----------
Data Analysis
Data Visualization
Data Warehousing
Big Data

Course Name
------------
Exam Readiness: Data Analysis
Exam Readiness: Data Visualization
Exam Readiness: Data Warehousing
Exam Readiness: Big Data
```

Basically, I'm trying to find out who took the exam readiness courses before they took the respective exam. Is there any way I can use LIKE clause on two columns? The only difference is, Course Name has "Exam Readiness" in the front.

I tried these two below:

1st query:

```
select * from table
where course_name like '%'+ exam_name + '%'
```

2nd query:

```
select * from table
WHERE COLUMNA LIKE '%'||COLUMNB||'%'
```

These are two different queries, not one query.

Comment: Your second query should already be working.  What happens when you actually run it?

Comment: Try to use query select * from table where exam_name like '%' || course_name || '%'

Comment: In SQL, `+` is the operator to add numbers, so the first query can't work, but the second uses the correct `||` operator and should work

Comment: When I try " select * from table where exam_name like '%' || course_name || '%' " it returns nothing, I also tried " select * from table where course_name like '%' || exam_name || '%' " it returns 0 results.

Comment: That certainly works: http://rextester.com/GLS89459  I guess there is something you are not telling us.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
SELECT
  foo
FROM exam
JOIN course ON (course.name = 'Exam Readiness: ' || exam.name)
```

Comment: This is a better solution than using `like` for the data that the OP provided.

Comment: Returns zero result.. :(

Comment: Well, then try to debug it. It will work once the column names are correctly matched.